# How do I do pow without the math.h library?

Tags: c

i have this code:

```
if (is_prime == 1) {
    for (marsennloop = 1, marsenn = 0; marsennloop <= calc; marsennloop++) {
        marsennloop = marsennloop * 2;
        marsenncalc2 = marsennloop - 1;
        if (marsenncalc2 == calc && calc != 1) {
            marsenn = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

on the line "marsennloop = marsennloop * 2;" i am trying to do a pow function without using pow but this give me an incorrect output when i change this line to pow and use the same variables i get the correct output which leads me to believe the problem lies within that line of code.

Comment: `x*2` is multiplying `x` by `2`, which is not the same as exponentiation. What are you trying to do? To calculate a square of the number?

Comment: When you write 'marsenn', is this meant to be Mersenne, as in Mersenne Primes?

Comment: i am trying to do a function that does 2^n-1 when n is a variable that starts at 1 and increases by 1 through every iteration of the loop

Comment: yes it is Mersenne primes

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming-exercises/numbers/c-numbers-exercise-33.php

Comment: So you want powers of `2` which is way simpler when done by computer. It is a simple bit manipulation.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mersenne-prime/

Comment: For integer `n`, you can express `2^n-1` as `(1U<<n) - 1`, provided `n` is less than the total number of bits available in the underlying integer type.  Note that `pow` is for general exponentiation and is largely inappropriate for integer base/exponent, especially integer powers of 2.  Unless you are working with floating-point values that will exceed integer ranges, and don't mind a potential loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

power of two (2^n) is simply shift `1 << n`

So naive function checking if the number is mersenne prime:

```
int ism(unsigned val)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(unsigned long long i = 2; i <= 1ULL << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(val)); i <<= 1)
    {
        if(i - 1 == val) 
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 1; i <= (1U << 20); i++)
    {
        if(ism(i)) 
        {
            printf("%u ", i);
            if(!(++count % 16)) printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the number is `2^n - 1`, please try the following function:

```
int is_m(unsigned int x)
{
    return (x & (x + 1)) == 0;
}
```

It returns `1` if x is `2^n - 1`, else returns `0`.